# Add a class to img of core/cover block

Tags: block-editor

I've searched everywhere, but I cannot find nothing about it, the question is simple: is there a way to add a class to the img of a standard gutenberg cover block?

Thanks and Regards!

Answer (score 0):

While it is (relatively) easy to add classes to most outer tag of block via [block hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/), it is not so easy what you want, since you'd have to change `save` function  via `getSaveElement` hook and basically recreate the HTML of the block with class inserted (as `className` attribute). You'd also have to change `Edit` function of the block via `BlockEdit` hook, in the similar way to have this class also applied in the editor.

It would be much more easy to just target img element inside with CSS selectors.